# Which value should be returned by a apollo graphql mutation?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, graphql

I'm using apollo graphql to call some mutation to change db data. I need some advice which value should be returned usually.

For `insertOne()` I would return the ID of the new document and for removing a dataset I would also return the ID, to remove the dataset on the client cache.

But what about `updateOne` - as it could be a very simple task as shown below, but sometimes it can do some complex update? I'm not quite sure which would be the most useful returning value.

In this simple example I'm just updating some content of a specific mongodb document. Right now the WriteResult of this method is returned. But is this really useful?

I see the follwing options:

1. Returning writeResult object - which has the need to be defined in the backend
2. Check *writeResult* and return boolean, e.g. result.nModified > 0
3. Return the content result - which would be at the end just the input content
4. Returning the updated document - which would need a `findOne({ _id: id })`
5. Just returning `true`, which maybe is not very useful?!

I know there is not a single solution for all use cases, but maybe someone could explain which way to go in general...

**server**

```
async updateContent(id, name, value) {
  const Content = this.db.collection('content')
  return Content.updateOne(
    { _id: id },
    { $set: { [name]: value } }
  )
}
```

**client**

```
updateContent({
  variables: { id, name, value }
})
  .then((response) => {
    // response.data.updateContent
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
```

**graphql**

```
mutation updateContent($id: ID!, $name: String, $value: String) {
  updateContent(id: $id, name: $name, value: $value) {
    nModified
  }
}
```

**schema**

```
type WriteResult {
  nModified: Int,
  nRemoved: Int,
  nInserted: Int,
  n: Int
  ok: Int
}

type Mutation {
  updateContent(id: ID!, name: String, value: String): ContentString
}
```

Comment: usually mutation resolver returns ... mutated type (but it's a graphql, you don't have to query for all fields/props; response will be filtered out; returning data = success) ... even deleted ones, surprise! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extending earlier comment ...

> usually mutation resolver returns ... mutated type (but it's a graphql, you don't have to query for all fields/props; response will be filtered out; returning data = success) ... even deleted ones, surprise! :D

**Returning mutated object type can be important for more advanced FE techniques** like [optimistic response](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/optimistic-ui/). This **helps you avoid refetching entire item list when you're updating one element**.

### in this case

**Types are not defined properly - this is your source of concerns**

Probably you should define it more like (input types are more manageable):

```
type ContentType {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
  author: User!
  createdAt: Date!
  updatedAt: Date!
}
type ContentCreateInputType {
  name: String!
  value: String!
}     
type ContentUpdateInputType {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  value: String!
}

type Stats {
  nModified: Int,
  nRemoved: Int,
  nInserted: Int,
  n: Int
  ok: Int
}    
type ContentUpdatePayload {
  content: ContentType
  stats: Stats
}    

type Mutation {
  updateContent(input: ContentUpdateInputType!): ContentUpdatePayload
}
```

This is a bit similiar idea to popular [relay style cursor pagination](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/cursor-based/#relay-style-cursor-pagination).

Your mutation can be:

```
mutation updateContent($input: ContentUpdateInputType) {
  updateContent(input: $input) {
    stats {
      nModified
    }
  }
}
```

... in this case your resolver must return only stats object, no `findOne` required ... but in practice it should return at least:

```
{ 
  content: {
    id
  }
  stats: {
    nModified
    nRemoved
    // etc.
  }
}
```

... because your mutation can be also:

```
mutation updateContent($input: ContentUpdateInputType) {
  updateContent(input: $input) {
    content {
      id
      content
      author {
        id
        name
      }
    }
    stats {
      nModified
    }
  }
}
```

**Returning `{ content: { id } stats: {....} }` (js object, the minimal mutation response) is neccessary (very important) to resolve entire query**. Server resolver will know it has not complete `ContentType` object (mutation `ContentUpdatePayload` element) and it will call `ContentType` resolver (with known/already resolved `id` as arg) to populate it (of course it will call `Author` type resolver, too).

As you can notice/see above, returning only a `content { id }` (from this mutation, part of `ContentType`) can be a part of the optimization - **no overfetching** - because `id` can be taken from mutation args and the entire content is resolved/read from DB/service only when required.

### conclusion

**Returning not typed responses simply doesn't allow this kind of 'GraphQL magic'.**